# send 404 File not found header, and then provide alternative file for download

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a file which contains a version number in the filename and is updated almost every month.(The version number is necessary for other software which needs that to work properly.)
To make published links with an old version number also workable, for user convenience, I wrote a php script which does a redirect with a 301 header, and provides the latest file with the current version number for download.

Now I found in the log file that old links with an old version number a kept in the index of search engines, and it's more and more growing that they aks for old files(urls), and even with the 301 redirect they do not update the stored links and ask for the old files over and over again. 
After reading a while I found that the only way to get them out of the index is to send a 404 or 410 header, but it seems on the other hand, that this doesn't let me send a file with that header.

So the question is do you see any chance how I can send a 404 or 410 header to get old links away from search engine indexes, and at the same time provide the latest file for download to have old links still working for user comfort?

Comment: are you sure the requests are coming from Search Results? and not other link pages that might not be updating?  most search engines should honor /update on the 301.

Comment: yes I store my redirects in a log file where I see which file was requested and the user_agent, which shows me that a lot of the requests come from search engines

Comment: but are actual end users getting sent to the old url from the search engine?  Or is it the spider/crawler just checking links?

Comment: it is the spider, e.g. bingbot,AhrefsBot,Googlebot...

Comment: well if it is just the spider, and not the actual end users, and you check in the search engine, and it isn't returning links to the old versions, it is probably safe to ignore. or say implement something that 404's the old versions save for the last one back, or perhaps implement something like teh answer below (But the spiders will probably still keep checking it, so you won't see redirects but 200s from them)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the meta http-eqiv attribute and JavaScript to allow requests from **browsers** to complete. This method will not work for `wget`, `curl` or other such automated programs.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>File not found</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://somedomain.tld/file_v1.txt"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>The requested resource does not exist. However, an older version of the file was found and will begin downloading in <span id="countdown">5</span> seconds.</p>
    <p>Please <a href="http://somedomain.tld/file_v1.txt">click here</a> if the download does not begin or you no longer wish to wait.</p>
    <script>
    // you can get #countdown and using setInterval decrease the seconds to enhance the user experience
    // additionally, you can use `window.location.href = "http://somedomain.tld/file_v1.txt";` at 0 seconds
    // incase the user has meta redirects disabled
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: based on comment on OP, This will probably do nothing as it is the Spider and not a browser..